# Coordinate type in postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Am getting an error when i try to insert data to postgis geometry column.

ERROR: Coordinate values are out of range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY type
SQL state: 22023

My insert query is.

```
INSERT INTO meter1(meter_id, meter_no,location,type) 
 VALUES ('M1', 200,ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=3857;  
        POINT(256300.11 9856321.09)'),'automatic' );
```

Comment: Well that error seems self explanatory both 256300.11 and 9856321.09 happen to be much much bigger than 180

Comment: e4c5 but how can insert that coordinate or what do i change

Comment: where does that data come from?

Comment: e4c5 it is  a subsection of the pipe network and meters.. The spatial reference id is 32737 (UTM Zone 37 South)
The following information is provided for the various entities.

Meters
MeterId Meter Number Location Type
M1 20345 (256 300.11, 9 856 321.09) Automatic
M2 20346 (256 922.39, 9 856 320.28) Manual
M3 20347 (257 673.53, 9 856 332.67) Automatic

Answer (score 1):

First of all it looks like one of the situations where you probably don't need to use the geography type.

> If your data is geographically compact (contained within a state, county or city), use the geometry type with a Cartesian projection that makes sense with your data.

http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/geography.html#why-not-use-geography

Having said that if you need to use the geography type after all you have to accept that geography columns can only save values in degrees and not in meters. Thus you will need to transform your data into a spacial ref sys that supports lat,lng. Thus your query will need to change as follows:

```
INSERT INTO meter1(meter_id, meter_no,location,type)    
VALUES ('M1', 200,
    ST_Transform(ST_SetSrid(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(256300.11 9856321.09)'), 3587), 4326),
    'automatic' );
```

The function to use here is [ST_Transform](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Transform.html)